# How I can solved this name is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, get, tkinter-entry

I want to make the program that I made can run
i make code like this

```
def cafe_food(self):
    friedrice_items = tk.Entry(F_FItems)
    friedrice_items.config(width=7, borderwidth=4, relief="sunken", font=("calibri", 10,"bold"),foreground="white", background="#248aa2")
    friedrice_items.place(x=81, y=1)

def Total_Biil(self):
    friedrice_price = 10
    pizza_price = 20

    if friedrice_items.get() != "":
        friedrice_cost = friedrice_price * int(friedrice_items.get())
    else:
        friedrice_cost = 0

    if pizza_items.get() != "":
        friedrice_cost = pizza_price * int(pizza_items.get())
    else:
        pizza_cost = 0

    total_bills = friedrice_cost + pizza_cost
```

if i run this code and..

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kisah tegar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Code\Python\Project\restaurant_mg\main.py", line 498, in Total_Bill
    if friedrice_items.get() != "":
NameError: name 'friedrice_items' is not defined
[Finished in 6.3s]
```

this my problem:(
how can i get friedrice_items in that function

Comment: Use global variables using the [global keyword](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword)

Comment: Since you're passing `self` to your methods, I suppose these methods are in a class, so your code block should contain the class too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this piece of code is in a class, try adding `self.` before you variable names:

```
def cafe_food(self):
    self.friedrice_items = tk.Entry(F_FItems)
    self.friedrice_items.config(width=7, borderwidth=4, relief="sunken", font=("calibri", 10,"bold"),foreground="white", background="#248aa2")
    self.friedrice_items.place(x=81, y=1)

def Total_Biil(self):
    self.friedrice_price = 10
    self.pizza_price = 20

    if self.friedrice_items.get() != "":
        self.friedrice_cost = self.friedrice_price * int(self.friedrice_items.get())
    else:
        self.friedrice_cost = 0

    if self.pizza_items.get() != "":
        self.friedrice_cost = self.pizza_price * int(self.pizza_items.get())
    else:
        self.pizza_cost = 0

    self.total_bills = self.friedrice_cost + self.pizza_cost
```

`self` or whatever you name it, is a [global keyword](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-keyword), where in a class, you can access the variable anywhere inside the class.

If you don't use `self` you would not be able to access it anywhere, like what happened to you before.